# XML Serialization issue

Tags: xml-serialization

I have the following classes

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("fileset")]
public class FileSet
{
    [XmlArray("")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName="file")]
    public List<File> Files { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("complete")]
    public string Complete { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("search_expression")]
    public string Search_Expression { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("format_expression")]
    public string Format_Expression { get; set; }

    public FileSet()
    { }

}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("file")]    
public class File
{
    [XmlElement("action")]
    public List<Action> Actions { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("format")]
    public string Format { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("filefound")]
    public string FileFound { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("filename")]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("size")]
    public long Size { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("creationTime")]
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

    public File() { }

}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("action")]
public class Action
{
    [XmlAttribute("task")]
    public string Task { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("sequenceid")]
    public int SequenceId { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("source")]
    public string Source { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("destination")]
    public string Destination { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("desc")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Action()
    { }

}
```

The xml which I provide is of the following type

```
<fileset complete="y" id="NY1109162" search_expression="" format_expression="">
  <file type="Datafile" format="NYyymmddn.zip" filefound="y" filename="NY1109162.zip" size="91703" creationTime="">
    <actions>
      <action task="move" sequenceid="1" source="" destination="" desc="move to archive"></action>
      <action task="copy" sequenceid="2" source="" destination="" desc="copy to production"></action>
      <action task="unzip" sequenceid="3" source="" destination="" desc="unzip files to working directory"></action>
    </actions>
  </file>
  <file type="Repfile" format="NYyymmddn.rep" filefound="y" filename="NY1109162.rep" size="17" creationTime="">
    <actions>
      <action task="copy" sequenceid="1" source="" destination="" desc="copy to archive"></action>
      <action task="copy" sequenceid="2" source="" destination="" desc="copy to production"></action>
    </actions>
  </file>
  <file type="Imagefile" format="NYyymmddn_images.zip" filefound="y" filename="NY1109162_images.zip" size="116550" creationTime="">
    <actions>
      <action task="move" sequenceid="1" source="" destination="" desc="move to archive"></action>
      <action task="copy" sequenceid="2" source="" destination="" desc="copy to production"></action>
      <action task="unzip" sequenceid="3" source="" destination="" desc="unzip files to working directory"></action>
    </actions>
  </file>
</fileset>
```

But when I serialize my FileSet object back to the xml, then it adds on extra tag  which I do not want.
The serialization output is,

```
<fileset complete="y" id="NY1109162" search_expression="" format_expression="">
<Files>
  <file type="Datafile" format="NYyymmddn.zip" filefound="y" filename="NY1109162.zip" size="91703" creationTime="">
    <actions>
      <action task="move" sequenceid="1" source="" destination="" desc="move to archive"></action>
      <action task="copy" sequenceid="2" source="" destination="" desc="copy to production"></action>
      <action task="unzip" sequenceid="3" source="" destination="" desc="unzip files to working directory"></action>
    </actions>
  </file>
  <file type="Repfile" format="NYyymmddn.rep" filefound="y" filename="NY1109162.rep" size="17" creationTime="">
    <actions>
      <action task="copy" sequenceid="1" source="" destination="" desc="copy to archive"></action>
      <action task="copy" sequenceid="2" source="" destination="" desc="copy to production"></action>
    </actions>
  </file>
  <file type="Imagefile" format="NYyymmddn_images.zip" filefound="y" filename="NY1109162_images.zip" size="116550" creationTime="">
    <actions>
      <action task="move" sequenceid="1" source="" destination="" desc="move to archive"></action>
      <action task="copy" sequenceid="2" source="" destination="" desc="copy to production"></action>
      <action task="unzip" sequenceid="3" source="" destination="" desc="unzip files to working directory"></action>
    </actions>
  </file>
</Files>
</fileset>
```

can anybody help please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you can change this - this looks like intended behaviour due the following - Deserializer should know where it should put your <file> entry back. So it put additional tag around your entries.
Imagine you will have 2 list typed properties

```
[XmlArray("")]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName="file")]
public List<File> Files { get; set; }

[XmlArray("")]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName="file")]
public List<File> ProcessedFiles { get; set; }
```

If you will be allowed to serialize all File entries to the childs of same level - you won't be able to deserialize it back - cause you are unable to specify - where each <file> should be put.

You can use manual xml serialization, if specified XML is strictly required and can't be changed.

Comment: yeah, absolutely right! I had not thought about that.Now I have implemented my own xml serializer.

Answer (score 0):

The `XmlSerializer` is not all that extensible.  If you're going to use it, you have to accept some compromises in your data format.  Here are some possible ways to get rid of that intervening element for the array:

- Change your `FileSet` class to directly override `List<File>` instead of having a separate list property. This gets rid of the outer element but you lose the ability to specify the name of the array item elements.
- Implement `IXmlSerializable` on your `FileSet` class. This is difficult as it forces you manually write your own serialization and deserialization code (which is usually what you want to avoid when using `XmlSerializer`).
- Stop using `XmlSerializer` and switch to a more flexible serializer such as the [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx). This is not quite as simple as `XmlSerializer` but it gives you more freedom to specify an exact format.